# Table filter in Report Builder DateDiff

Tags: function, reporting-services, datediff

I want to add a filter to a table in Report Builder. I want to get only the records from the last 12 hours. I have tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
DateDiff(HOUR,TimeOfDay(),Fields!Modified.Value) <=12
```

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
=Iif(DateDiff(DateInterval.Hour, Fields!Modified.Value, Now()) <= 12, 1, 0)
```